# Блоки текста выезжают на gap grid сетки, как исправить?

Tags: html, вёрстка

[image]

При адаптиве на ширине разрешения 320px почему-то блоки текста вылазят на grid-gap.

[image]

Нужно, чтобы было вот так!

```css
.work {
     &__list {
      list-style: none;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      row-gap: 32px;
      margin-bottom: 56px;
    }
    &__item {
      display: flex;
    }
    &__item__img {
      width: 56px;
      height: 56px;
      margin-right: 16px;
    }
    &__item__title {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 150%;
      width: 216px;
      max-height: 48px;
    }
    &__item__text {
      width: 216px;
      max-height: 72px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 171.429%; 
    }
  }
```

```html
  <ul class="work__list">
    <li class="work__item">
      <img
        class="work__item__img"
        src="../images/waiting.jpg"
        alt="waiting.jpg"
      />
      <div class="work__item__content">
        <h6 class="work__item__title">Прочитай задание внимательно</h6>
        <p class="work__item__text">
          Думаю у тебя не займет это больше двух-трех минут
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="work__item">
      <img
        class="work__item__img"
        src="../images/delivery-truck.jpg"
        alt="delivery-truck.jpg"
      />
      <div class="work__item__content">
        <h6 class="work__item__title">Изучи весь макет заранее</h6>
        <p class="work__item__text">
          Подумай как это будет работать на разных разрешениях и при скролле
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="work__item">
      <img
        class="work__item__img"
        src="../images/secure.jpg"
        alt="secure.jpg"
      />
      <div class="work__item__content">
        <h6 class="work__item__title">Сделай хорошо</h6>
        <p class="work__item__text">
          Чтобы мы могли тебе доверить подобные задачи в будущем
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="work__item">
      <img
        class="work__item__img"
        src="../images/money-bags.jpg"
        alt="money-bags.jpg"
      />
      <div class="work__item__content">
        <h6 class="work__item__title">Получи предложение</h6>
        <p class="work__item__text">
          Ну тут все просто, не я придумал правила, но думаю так и будет)))
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в классе `&__item__text` с ограничением высоты текста `max-height: 72px;`.